# Debugging iOS app opened through custom url

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I have created two ios app `A` & `B`. I made custom URL for app `A` and tried to opened it through app `B`. But the app `A` crashes when it opened. I want to debug it. How will I do that?

Comment: Do not negate the question. If you find it silly enough first give solution to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you know how to debug (if not, that's a different question), and that your problem is how to set a breakpoint when the application is launched from a URL rather than by yourself directly.

What you need to do is to setup breakpoints normally anywhere you need them - e.g. in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` Then

1. Click on your application name 'A' in the bar and then Edit Scheme. 
   [image]
2. Under Info, select "Wait for executable to be launched"
   [image]
3. Run app 'A' from Xcode. It will not actually run, but prepare to debug it when it is run.
4. Now run app 'B' and launch app 'A' from it.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on the break point navigator in the xcode
- Press the plus icon at the bottom left of the window and add an Exception Break point.

It will give you enough information when the app crashes and you will be able to back track and find the cause

[image]

Comment: In which app should I put this. I added it in app A but not getting any thing

Comment: I did this itself, but nothing happened

Comment: Run the Project A and try to open the app A from B.it should give you heads up